# How do I pass multiple arguments to an anonymous function in PHP?

Tags: php, callback, anonymous-function

PHP 5.3+ supports [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (although, it supports them a tad bit differently in PHP 7.x+ in terms of binding). I am running PHP 5.6.x

Is there a syntax that allows for *multiple arguments* to be passed to an anonymous function (without resorting to using just an array) *being used as a **callback***. Which of these examples, if any, are possible in PHP?

**Example 1**

```
function ($str1, $str2 ){   //But, that would be too easy, right?
    return $str1 . $str2;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
function () use ($string, $min, $max) {  // Not seeing this in the manual.
    $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
    return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);
}
```

**Example 3**

Just out of curiosity, is this form possible?

```
function ($str1, $str2 ) use ($int1, $int2) { // But, that would be in the manual?
    return $str1 . $str2 .' '. $int2 + $int2;
}
```

I looked in the PHP manual, but didn't see what I was looking for.

Comment: All 3 forms are possible; but standard arguments are passed at the point where the function is called; "use" arguments at the point where the closure is defined

Comment: With PHP 5.6, you can also use argument packing/unpacking with the `...` operator: `function (...$args){
    return implode($args);
}`

Comment: @MarkBaker Your explanation of the the `use` arguments should be in the PHP manual. I understand that better now. Thank you. I learned about anonymous functions and closure in JavaScript ... I'm not trying to make an exact parallel. I just mean to say that I *understand* when you say "where the closure is defined." Excellent.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you. I will have to look up argument packing/unpacking. Cheers.

Comment: Re `use`: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160

Comment: @miken32 Ah, I see that last example had one normal, and one `use` parameter defined. Ok.

Comment: Example 2 was useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 works for me.

```
function () use ($string, $min, $max) {  // Not seeing this in the manual.
    $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
    return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);
}
```